# Find a certain index based on what user inputs

Tags: python

This is what my data looks like:

```
Symbol         Amount 
BB             1000 
TIS            8574 
LIG            1333 
etc...         etc... 
etc...
```

The symbol represents a stock and the amount is the share in that stock. I want to be able to ask the user what stock they want and then return that share.

This is the code I have

```py
def find_amount(port, stock_symbol):
    for item in port:
        if item == stock_symbol:
        print(item)
```

Comment: is BB, TIS, LIG symbols?

Comment: Yes, they are the symbols and the digits are their values.

Comment: A dictionary may be a better choice for this problem since it provides direct access to the value if you use the stock ticker as the dictionary key

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to try to do something without a dictionary but  I see how that can work also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
for item in port:
    if item[0] == stock_symbol:
        print (item[1])
```

I hope this may be of help.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment from @Carlos: a dict is the way to do this:

```
in: tickers = {'BB': 1000, 'TIS': 8574, 'LIG': 1333, etc.}
```

Then to access the value of any ticker you simply pass in the stock name:

```
in: tickers['BB']
out: 1000
```

and it will return the value. No function needed.

Dictionary is section 5.5 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).